# Получить значения выборного елемента autocomplete js

Tags: php, javascript

Есть таблица

```
  $(document).ready(function(){                                                                                         
   var product = ["<?php echo  $product; ?>"];
   var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td><input type='text'  id='tags' name='product_name[]' autocomplete='on' required class='form' onchange='product_name(this)'></td>" +
            "<td width='180'><input name='model_product[]'   type='text'   class='form-control'  ></td>" +
            "<td style='width: 15%'><input style='width: 45%' type='text' name='price[]'> <input style='width: 45%' readonly type='text' name='currency[]' ></td>"+
            "<td width='120'><input type='text' name='total[]'  class='form-control' id='i1'  ><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  class='form-control'  ></td>" +
            "<td><img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1); sum_total(this);'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id=i2  value='0' size='1' >" +
            "<img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);sum_total(this);'></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='oll_total[]' class=i3></td>" +
            "<td><a id='delete_row' class=' minus' onclick='sum_delete(this)'><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='<?php echo $text_delete_product; ?>'></a></td></td>");
        $('#addr'+i).find('.form').autocomplete(
                {source: product}
        ); // здесь выпадавший список   
        i++;

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
$("#delete_row").click(function(){
    if(i > 1 ){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
    }
});
});

     jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
});
```

я передаю выбранное значение так выбрал из списка после того кликнул рядом с input и данные погрузились

```
function product_name(element){
var row = $(element).closest("tr");
var name_product = row.find("input[name='product_name[]']").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/autocomplete',
    data:{"name_product":name_product},
    success: function (data) {
        row.find("input[name='model_product[]']").val(data);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/total',
    data:{"name_model":name_product},
    success: function(data){
        row.find("input[name='total[]']").val(data);
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/currency',
    data:{"name_model":name_product},
    success: function(data){
        row.find("input[name='currency[]']").val(data);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/product_id',
    data:{"name_model":name_product},
    success: function(data){
        row.find("input[name='product_id[]']").val(data);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/price',
    data:{"name_model":name_product},
    success: function(data){
        row.find("input[name='price[]']").val(data);
    }
});}
```

а можно получить выбранное значения по клику по нем ?

Comment: я правильно понял проблему? Вы поулчаете значения когда начинаете писать в инпут, а хотели бы сразу как кликните на него?

Comment: @Jurij Jazdanov да хотелось при клике на выбранное

Comment: onchange поменяйте на onclick

Comment: Такое реально сделать, просто у меня все сделано так, я начинаю писать, у меня выпадает список  я выбираю из списка и получаю значения после того как кликаю на другой input я его могу отследить в консоле

Comment: Не срабатывает идет клик на input получаю пустое значения выбираю из списка не чего не происходит и после того как еще раз кликнул получаю значение